# Mysql GROUP BY or DISTINCT query usage in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, distinct

I'm a little bit confused about these kind of new query types for me (DISTINCT,GROUP BY etc.)
I have three tables in my database.

- BRANDS
- PRODUCTS
- RECIPES

What I would like to do is to list BRANDS then look for PRODUCTS of that brand and look if there is a RECIPE of those products, then I want it to be written.

I'm able to write it with the basic queries;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM BRANDS";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE BRANDID = 1";
       $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM RECIPES WHERE PRODUCTID = 2";
```

but it repeats the brands.As far as I googled I have to use GROUP BY or DISTINCT in my query.

How should I create my query layout and which of them I should use?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you either a. Need to use a loop, or, b. use inner joins

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you necessarily need to do all the distinct and grouping, unless your database has duplicate rows. You can select all of that in one query like so:

```
Select Brands.BrandId, Brands.BrandName, Products.ProductId, Products.ProductName, Recipes.*
From Brands
Inner Join Products On Products.BrandId = Brands.BrandId
Inner Join Recipes On Recipes.ProductId = Products.ProductId
Where
    Brands.BrandId = 1 And
    Products.ProductId = 2
Order By Brands.BrandId, Products.ProductId, Recipes.RecipeId
```

Please note that I assumed you have a Brands.BrandName and Products.ProductName column. This query will get you a complete recordset, filtered based on Brand and Product.